# Input/Output Error in /media

Tags: mount, input

I accidentally ran

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media
```

Since then I get an Input/Output error when trying to make a directory in /media.

I'm using lubuntu. Every usb device is automatically mounted in /media. So at the moment I can't mount anything.
Help please!

Comment: Have you tried unmounting /dev/sdc1? You can't mount multiple partitions under the same directory. Try something like /media/external instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't mount multiple partitions under the same directory. Separate mount points mount points should be made for each, such as, for example:

```
/media/external01
/media/external02
/media/...
```

By default, Ubuntu creates mount point of the following path:

```
/media/username/mountpoint
```

So to get rid of your problem, unmount first and then remount using the advice above.